# How to profile with Code:Blocks

Tags: c++, profiling, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm making a wxWidget application for windows. I'm working with code:blocks 13.12 and MinGW 4.8 in windows 7.

I enable the -pg option in `settings->compiler` and after compiling try to open the `plugins->code profiler` and the result is this:

> gprof:
>   file`C:\Users\josele\Documents\C_C++\DLL\SQLManager\bin\Release\SQLManager.exe'
>   has no symbols

Basicly I don't know how profiling works in code:block and also my general knowledge of profiling is quite reduced.

I'm looking for solve this or a tutorial of: how profiling works in code:blocks?.

If you need more information, only let me know. Thank you in advance.

PD. I also run the `.exe` before calling the `plugins->code profiler` with a positive exit of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solve that problem with this posts:

> http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=12237.0
>   http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=14798.0

I went to `Project->build options` and there I turn off optimizations and enable the pofiler.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was turning off the "-s" compiler flag, which seems to be on by default in CB release flags.